# Nested DataGridView controls always seem to prioritize the parent DGV for arrow key navigation and not the DGV that is actually in focus

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Meaning if i try to edit a text cell in a DataGridView that is a child of another DGV and decide to navigate through the text with the arrow keys; the Parent DGV takes priority of this input.

Hoping that there's a fix for this without having to rework my database manager so that this doesn't happen.

here's a sample project i made but i don't know a way of linking it:
[image: demonstration]

here's the code i used to add the child DGV using that button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        Program.mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        Program.mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        DataGridView x = new DataGridView();
        x.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 100);
        x.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 200);


        // how the child is added
        Program.mainForm.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(x);
        


        var newCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "boi", HeaderText = "boi" };
        x.Columns.Add(newCol);
        x.Rows.Add();
        x.Rows.Add();
    }
```

Comment: How did you add the child dgv? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why are you adding a `DataGridView` as a child control of a different `DataGridView` to begin with?

Comment: @Loathing This is for "subtables" in my Database manager project.
https://github.com/KnightNine/ManorDB
it's convenient to do so because the `Location` of children controls exist relative to the parent.

Comment: Since i have subtables within subtables, i'd need to reference their locations from a dictionary whenever i open a new subtable since they are positioned underneath the row with the button cell that opened it, and whenever i close a subtable i'll need to create a loop that goes through to remove all that subtable's children.
So it's a bit of extra work to just use separate grids but if there's no easy solution to this issue that's what i'll have to do.

Comment: Displaying the child `DataGridView` hosted in a popup `ToolStripDropDown` might be an alternative option to consider. When a button is clicked, just show the drop down menu at that button location, and give the popup the focus.

Comment: @JohnG oh, i thought you meant separate in regards to not being joined by a hierarchy of parents and children. 
But in regards to your first comment; yeah, i'm already using two separate grids then.

Comment: @Loathing gives me an idea that if adding a "buffer parent" by inserting the child DGV in a parent `panel` or something instead of directly into the parent DGV.
that might work. i'll need to try it then i'll try your idea.

Comment: @Loathing the "buffer parent" idea didn't work with `Panel` and you can't put a `DataGridView` inside a `ToolStripDropDown`.

Comment: @DED Yes you can by using `ToolStripControlHost`.

Comment: @Loathing thanks that worked to get a control into a `ToolStripDropDown` (TSDD) but it unfortunately it comes with other issues...
I want the `DataGridView` (DGV) to be persistent even when I'm not using it and `TSDD` closes itself when losing focus. Forcing `TSDD` to stay open makes it so I can't use any other `DGV` that isn't inside the `TSDD` for some reason.

Looks like I'll just need to manage the DGV positions manually if I don't find a solution.

Comment: @DED `ToolStripDropDownMenu menu = ...; menu.AutoClose = false;`